# Unknown values shown in my site URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am busy in developing webapp. when I published this site, I saw unknown values in my URL before my site directory and this value changes on every page of the Website. I searched in my project but its not in my project directory and even not in my database.Please Help.
thanks in advance. Unknown value highlighted in yellow [image: unknown value highlighted in yellow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use cookieless session state (it is passed inside URL) instead of using browser cookies. This is something to configure in web.config

Check [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) and [SessionState explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx)